# How to create linear gradient with thousands of properties in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm making a really in-efficient redrawing tool that takes each pixel of a canvas and takes it's color values and plugs that data into a linear gradient CSS property on a separate div. I want the linear gradient to create a non-fading effect where every pixel is going to have a separate color. I also don't know how the linear gradient will align with my pixel-color values since it reads every line one by one.

**My other values like percent and data are arbitrary because I already have that figured out**

```
        var data=(img_ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1).data);
        draw.style.background+=" ,linear-gradient(0deg, "+Math.floor(percent)+"%, rgba("+data+")";
```

I just got a div that has no style properties for background, and I added the comma to allow multiple colors, I'm just not sure how to use linear gradient well enough to figure this out.

Comment: So, if I take a 3000x2000 photo from my disk and store it in the `canvas` you are going to create some gradient with (potentially) 6 million colors? I'm not mocking you: a 500x500 element already has 250,000 pixels you need to process. What sizes are we talking about? Users have a very tiny 'patience span'...

Comment: Here's something I created over a year ago, not sure if you are looking for this: [Codepen: rainbow map](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/vYJYQGE). Check the Javascript for `ct.createLinearGradient`.

Comment: The images are 256x256 in size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear gradients have only a single axis and fill their container in the perpendicular direction. In other words, you can only control the width of a color along that axis, making it impossible to create a 1px x 1px color within a div larger than 1px.

So the only way to achieve the redraw is to create a stack of divs with 1px of height (or columns with 1px width).

You can then contain the colors to 1px along the main axis by adding two stops for each color indicating the start and end along the main axis.

```js
const scale = 0.1;

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const img = new Image();
img.onload = onload;

fetch('https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/006/428/637738.jpg')
  .then((res) => res.blob())
  .then((blob) => (img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)));

function onload() {
  const w = img.width * scale;
  const h = img.height * scale;
  canvas.width = w;
  canvas.height = h;
  canvas.style.width = w.toString() + 'px';
  canvas.style.height = h.toString() + 'px';

  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);

  const pixelData = Array.from(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h).data);

  for (let row = 0; row < h; row++) {
    const rowDiv = document.createElement('div');
    rowDiv.style.width = w.toString() + 'px';
    rowDiv.style.height = '1px';

    const rowStart = row * w * 4;
    let background = 'linear-gradient(to right,';
    for (let col = 0; col < w; col++) {
      const pixelStart = rowStart + col * 4;
      background +=
        'rgba(' +
        pixelData[pixelStart] +
        ',' +
        pixelData[pixelStart + 1] +
        ',' +
        pixelData[pixelStart + 2] +
        ',' +
        pixelData[pixelStart + 3] +
        ')' + col + 'px ' + (col + 1) + 'px,';
    }
    rowDiv.style.background = background.slice(0, -1) + ')';
    document.body.append(rowDiv);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Canvas</h1>
<canvas></canvas>

<h1>Gradients</h1>
```

But at this point you might as well just make a div for every pixel.

Comment: Fun how this ended up, but I get the distinct feeling OP wants to convert a pic to a gradient because of *I want the linear gradient to create a non-fading effect where every pixel is going to have a separate color*. A `background` with 108 linear gradients, each with 192 colors. *Non-fading* would mean each start/stop has to shift 1/192th percent per pixel. Interpreting this from the brief example code. Totally unsure, but it seems to make more sense, esp. with larger pics (OP commented to require 256x256). Anyway, going to toy with your code...tnx for that!

Comment: So like, just redrawing the image pixel by pixel?

Comment: That's my guess, with a list of `linear-gradient`s. But OPs reactions are a bit in the wind, so I'm messing with it on Codepen right now, seems fun enough.

Comment: @RenevanderLende ok, edited for that.

Comment: I used your solution and created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/poZRBRY) with custom variables and range sliders to toy with output sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, also the ending sentence on how I should just draw every div with the color, tried it before and it was real slow.